# insert data into database. Cakephp, AJAX, jQuery, Async

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, cakephp

I have a very simple task to do. I have a value assigned to in my front-end which I would like to send as asynchronously to my back-end.

The following html code inside my view:

```
<p id="p">Test</p>
    <form id='formId' onclick="save()"  method="post">
        <input class="save" type="submit" value="save" > </input>
    </form>
```

I am getting the content which I want to send as async with the following jQuery code:

```
function save() {
    var savedVal = $("#p").text();
    if (savedVal.length > 0) {
        $("#p").text("saving...");
        $("#p").text("");
        return savedVal
    }
    else
    alert("There is nothing to send!");
}
```

I want the value of `savedVal` to be sent async to my controller and from there to save it in my database.

Comment: Instead of onclick="save()" is should be onsubmit="save()". The <input> element doesn't need a closing element. You can use <input />.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you have an idea on how to send post data via ajax. My answer will concentrate on the CakePHP controller action part of your question.

in your controller

```
public function saveJSON()
{
    $jsonResponseArray = [] //Your response array
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {
      $myModelEntity = $this->MyModel->newEntity($this->request->data);
      $mySavedData = $this->MyModel->save($myModelEntity);
      if($mySavedData)
      {
        $jsonResponseArray = ; //Whatever data you want to send as a response
      }
      else
      {
         //Save failed
          $jsonResponseArray = ; //Whatever data you want to send as a response
       }

     }
        $json = json_encode($jsonResponseArray);
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->response->type ( 'json' );
        $this->response->body ( $json );
}
```

FYI this answer is in CakePHP 3.0

```
  ///A bit of JQuery to get you started
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "http://" + window.location.hostname
                + "/Controller/saveJSON",
        data: {
            p: $('#p').val()
        },
        success: function(result) {
           //JSON seponse comes the the variable named result
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        global: false
    });
```